# Char Vs Byte in Oracle

Tags: oracle, character-encoding, char, byte

I am comparing two databases which have similar schema. Both should support unicode characters.

When i describe the same table in both database, *db 1* shows all the varchar fields with char, (eg `varchar(20 char))` but the *db2* shows without `char`, `(varchar(20)`

the second schema supports only one byte/char.

When i compare `nls_database_parameters` and `v$nls_parameters` in both database its all same.

could some one let me know what may be the change here?

Comment: Aren't they warchar2 not varchar?

Comment: @San - What is the database character set from `v$nls_parameters`?  Is the database character set `AL32UTF8`?  What, exactly, is the problem?  `CHAR` vs `BYTE` semantics do not affect what characters can be stored in a column.  They may influence how many characters can be stored in a column depending on the particular characters.

Answer (score 3):

Have you checked NLS_LENGTH_SEMANTICS? You can set the default to BYTE or CHAR for CHAR/VARCHAR2 types.

If these parameters are the same on both datbases then maybe the table was created by explicitly specifying it that way.